# How to handle response from slow server

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5, angular7

I have to get some data from a server .The response from server comes very slowly. I want store the response in a an array so that it can display in template . The aim is to delay the storing of response into an array till the server returns response

I already tried  setTimeout() but , it fails

### Ts file

```
ticketdetails()
{
  this.funName = 'online_service';
  var url = { url:'bookingdetails?username=....&password=....&bookingCode=' + this.id};
  console.log(url);
  this.myservice.online_service(this.funName,url).subscribe(response => {

 if (response.code === '1') 
   {
     this.bookDetails = response;
     console.log('Book details inside function', this.bookDetails);
   }
  })
  console.log('Book details outside function' , this.bookDetails)
}
```

In console , 
Book details inside function displays the response result from server
but,
Book details outside function displays as null .

Comment: you can use boolean to handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do all the operations/assignments in callback of function call.
As call will be asynchronous, so until you didn't get response from server your further code will not be executed.

The code after the API call will be executed so I think API call should be designed in the way that it's response will be wrapped in callback and then it will be used.
The code you write after API call will immediately executed after that line, it will not wait for the response to arrive as it's obvious nature of Java script.

Sample: **Rest Service**

```
customHttpDefaultOptions= {
     headers: new HttpHeaders({
             'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     })
};

postRestCall(requestBody, data) {
    this.httpClient.post(apiURL, requestBody, this.customHttpDefaultOptions).pipe(retry(1))
            .subscribe(response => {
            data(response);
    }, error => data(this.handleError(error)));
}
```

So here you should also do something and once response arrive it will be wrapped inside callback and you can use it later on from callback.

Sample:

```
this.restService.postRestCall(requestBody, data => {
    this.his.bookDetails = data;
});
```

So if you have made kind of rest service then you can also re-use the API call mechanism rather than writing boiler plate code of api call.

It's not issue of slowness at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - isResponce: boolean =false;

       ticketdetails()
       {
         this.funName = 'online_service';
         var url = { url:'bookingdetails?username=....&password=....&bookingCode=' +
   this.id};
         console.log(url);
         this.myservice.online_service(this.funName,url).subscribe(response =>
   {

        if (response.code === '1') 
          {
            this.isResponce = true;
            this.bookDetails = response`enter code here`;
            console.log('Book details inside function', this.bookDetails);
          }
         })
```